# PHP Unique MultiDimensional Array Issue

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

So, I am getting unique values from my MD array utilizing the following function:

```
    function unique_multidim_array($array, $key) { 
        $temp_array = array(); 
        $i = 0; 
        $key_array = array();           
        foreach( $array as $val ) { 
            if ( ! in_array( $val[$key], $key_array ) ) { 
                $key_array[$i] = $val[$key]; 
                $temp_array[$i] = $val; 
            }
            $i++; 
        } 
        return $temp_array; 
    }
```

My array is similar to the following:

```
Array (
    [0] =>
        Array (
            'name' => 'Nevada'
        )
    [1] =>
        Array (
            'name' => 'Colorado'
        )
    [2] =>
        Array (
            'name' => 'Nevada'
        )
    [3] =>
        Array (
            'name' => 'Colorado'
        )
    [4] =>
        Array (
            'name' => 'Oklahoma'
        )
    [5] =>
        Array (
            'name' => 'Nevada'
        )
    [6] =>
        Array (
            'name' => 'Nevada'
        )
)
```

And using the function (`unique_multidim_array ( $term_arr, 'name' )`) above I am getting a single `Nevada` and a single `Colorado`, however, it is not returning `Oklahoma`

What can I do to ensure that it will return unique values, even if there are no duplicates?

Comment: What PHP version? It's working for me [here](https://3v4l.org/WQBa2)

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/k8in-xv05

Comment: php7 on a Lemp box

Comment: Not sure if you can view this...  but it's in use here: http://getme.onl/portfolio/multi-family   the tabs should show Colorado, Nevada, Oklahoma, California

Comment: How are you iterating over the resulting array? Depending on how it might be of no importance, but do notice that the indices are preserved, Oklahoma's array in the resulting array is 4.

Comment: I just set the page to dump the real array in a textbox above

Comment: I can't load you website. Try changing this line `$temp_array[$i] = $val;` for this line `$temp_array[] = $val;` though it might be of no difference

Comment: @ishegg can you post as an answer?  `$term_arr = array_values ( unique_multidim_array ( $term_arr, 'name' ) );` fixed it :)

Comment: LOL  yeah, I have to clear cache, and restart nginx/php-fpm on the server with every `code` change :)

Comment: Done. Glad you could get it sorted out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your resulting array keeps the original indices, and, depending on how you are iterating over it, you might get unexpected results. Try resetting the indices:

```
function unique_multidim_array($array, $key) { 
    $temp_array = array(); 
    $i = 0; 
    $key_array = array();           
    foreach( $array as $val ) { 
        if ( ! in_array( $val[$key], $key_array ) ) { 
            $key_array[$i] = $val[$key]; 
            $temp_array[] = $val; // <--- remove the $i
        }
        $i++; 
    } 
    return $temp_array; 
}
```

Or, as you say, `array_values()` will help too:

```
$term_arr = array_values ( unique_multidim_array ( $term_arr, 'name' ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP already has a function to remove duplicates from an array

```
array_unique(array)
```

should do the trick

Comment: aye, but it didn't because of the mulitdimensionalness of it

Comment: array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array))) could do it...

Comment: According to the docs: "Two elements are considered equal if and only if (string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2". So it can't works for multidimensional array
The serialize/unserialize option could works but looks dirty.